# Wall-E Axiom Spaceships

Tags: wall-e, pixar

At the start of *Wall-E*, there was an enormous amount of billboards with "BnL". At the metro, an exit had one with the ad where Shelby shows us how many spaceliners launched. During all the movie we saw only one actual ship, which at the end landed to the Earth.

So, the question is:

1) Where are other ships and what happened to them?

2) Why does only one ship provide operations with EVE on Earth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Where are other ships and what happened to them?

The movie does not provide us with the answer as to what happens to the other ships. 
At this point we can do nothing but to speculate all those whats and whys.

Of course you don't clutter all those giant ships at one place. They are spread across the universe (well within permissible distance). Those were not shown probably as the story can run independently without any necessary inputs from them.

> 2) Why does only one ship provide operations with EVE on Earth?

We see Buy-N-Large has the monopoly of overseeing the welfare of people and the society. They have the power of governance in the spacecraft and we can assume that they had are in control of other spaceships too. So, when one unit of them is sending EVE to check the status of earth, the other units refrain themselves from wasting their work power.

Also there is another possibility. Others may have sent other EVEs in other parts of the earth, but they didn't end up with the interesting events as EVE does, so we don't need them in the story.

Comment: Could also be that the other ships were sent on throughout the solar system/galaxy, and this particular Axiom was kept behind within decent distance of Earth and was tasked with being the "survey" ship to watch Earth for any signs of life. Hence being the only one with EVE operations/returning. It could be (during the credits at the end) that the other Axioms eventually returned over time. (speculation, hence comment)

Comment: Yes, that too is possible !